# Delay Subroutine Time Calculation

Tags: pic, microchip

How do I calculate the total time consumed by a subroutine in PIC? It is given that  the PIC master clock is derived from a 1MHz crystal. Here is the code given:

```
TEMP   EQU 0x1D

DELAY  MOVLW 0x80
       MOVWF TEMP
       NOP
DELAY1 NOP
       DECFSZ  TEMP,F
       GOTO    DELAY1
       RETURN
```

I have calculated that there are a total of 518 instruction cycles and the total number of Q-cycles = 2072. 
How would I go on about if the clock is at 2MHz? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 8 Bit PIC:

> > instruction cycle Time  = 4 / fOzs

1MHz means an instruction cyle of 4us. So your code will execute in 518 x 4us = 2,072ms.

2MHz means an instruction cycle of 2us. So your code will execute in 518 x 2us = 1,036ms.

Answer (score 0):

All 8-bit data path PIC controllers use 4 oscillator clocks for 1 instruction cycle. CHanges to the oscillator frequency do not change this relationship.

The code you posted always executes in 518 instruction cycles.

When the oscillator frequency is changed from 1 MHz to 2 MHz the code will execute in less real time but will still use the same number of instruction cycles.